# Problem authenticating Vue SPA in Laravel API Sanctum

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-api

I am having a problem authenticating Vue SPA with Laravel API.

The Laravel application path is http://backend.local
The Vue App is sending requests from http://localhost:8082

Here are the steps that i have taken.

Followed the instructions at Laravel Sanctum Page for installations and configuration.

Allowed CORS access from everywhere in nginx by adding

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;
```

Here is the route
api.php

```
Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'authenticate'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Here is the portion of code where axios makes a request.

```
axios.defaults.withcredentials = true;
attempt() {
        axios.get("http://backend.local/sanctum/csrf-cookie").catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
  });
},
login() {
  this.attempt();
  axios
    .post("http://backend.local/api/login", this.formdata)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
},
```

However i am unable to authenticate my application. Checking the Network tab shows that my application has recieved a CSRF-Token, but for some reason it can't be authenticated. Attached Screenshots display the error. I am getting Unauthenticated message and have absolutely no idea what's gone wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGaU1.jpg)

[Unauthenticated Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UHC.jpg)

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoSEx.jpg)

Comment: Your attached images are not good and cropped. Please explain more about your error.

Comment: It returns an error "Unauthenticated"

Comment: Please read this section `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. ` https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Update your question to meet Stackoverflow recommendations.